# Angular 2 filter and toggle function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have created a hamburger menu and there is toggle function for displaying subcategories this toggle function is working fine until i apply filter on them. After searching a category through filter toggle function not working.

this is my html code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<div id="menuToggle" class="sidenav">
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
   <input class="form-control" type="search" [(ngModel)]="txtToSearch" placeholder="Search"/>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let category of (componentContents.dashboardMenu | dashboardFilter : txtToSearch); let i = index" >
   <p class="toggleMenu" (click)="toggleMenu(i,componentContents.dashboardMenu)">{{category.category}}
    </p>

    <div *ngIf="category.show">
      <ul id="{{(category.category).split(' ').join('-')}}" *ngIf="category.subCategory.length > 0">
        <li *ngFor="let subCat of category.subCategory">
          <a routerLink={{subCat.router}} routerLinkActive="active">             
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" ></span>{{subCat.subcategory}} </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </li>
</ul>
```

in component.ts im using this code for toggle function

```
toggleMenu(index, catArry) {
if (catArry[this.prevClicked] && this.prevClicked !== index) {
  catArry[this.prevClicked].show = false;
}
catArry[index].show = !catArry[index].show;
this.prevClicked = index;
 }
```

Comment: The index changes in view when filter is applied and the index does not match with the model collection I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` variable is applicable only to the current result. So when the filter is applied, the result changes and the index does not correspond to the actual position of element in array.

You can pass the category itself to the `toggleMenu(category, catArray)` function instead of index and calculate the index in `toggleMenu` function using `catArray.indexOf(category)`

Comment: Thanks i tried that but got error can not read property show of undefined

Comment: Can you please paste your updated code here or create a plunker out of it?

Comment: toggleMenu(category, catArry) {
    let index = catArry.indexOf(category);
    console.log("Index Value"+index);
    if (catArry[this.prevClicked] && this.prevClicked !== index) {
      catArry[this.prevClicked].show = false;
    }
    catArry[index].show = !catArry[index].show;
    this.prevClicked = index;
  }

Comment: Getting -1 index value after applying filter

Comment: Try using `findIndex` method to find the category from array instead of `indexOf`.

Comment: Just log catArray and category to see if category is present in array

Comment: Im able to solve it by adding  category.show = !category.show; in toggle function thanks for guiding me :)